# PostgreSQL isset function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

Is there any way, how to check, whether a variable has already been set in my environment?

Example:

```
\set table_name countries
\i queries.sql
```

queries.sql:

```
SELECT * FROM :table_name;
```

I want to make queries.sql to be called independently and use some default table name I would specify.

Is this possible or do I really need to create another SQL file through which I will call the queries (\i)?

My use case is usage of my SQL queries both in pgTAP unit tests (with some sample table names) and independently.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the current value with:

```
SELECT :'table_name';
```

You can set it on the call to psql with something like `--set='table_name'` on the psql command line.